# Do Black Bolt's powers work in space?

Tags: marvel, inhumans, blackbolt

The king of the Attilan and the well-known Inhuman Black Bolt is arguably one of the most powerful characters in the Marvel universe. His quasi-sonic scream can bring about a lot of destruction and even a single whisper can level entire cities.

My question, however, is related to his said powers in space/vacuum. Sound cannot travel in a vacuum. So, if he is, to say, trapped in such an environment, his sonic-scream is completely useless.

Or is my understanding of his powers incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[His powers are not actually based on sound](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Blackagar_Boltagon_(Earth-616)), and are in fact fairly universally described as "quasi-sonic".

> Black Bolt's primary superhuman ability is the power to harness electrons. The speech center of his brain contains a unique organic mechanism that's able to generate an unknown particle that interacts with the electrons he absorbs to create certain phenomena that are determined by his mental control.

So, in other words, as long as there is something that allows for the propagation of electrons, his blast is only triggered by his attempt to speak or otherwise make sound with his vocal cords, but it is not dependent on sound.

Comment: It just happens to be linked to his speech section of his brain.

Comment: @Naib: Yup. So if you convinced him he could not speak, he might not be able to harness his problems.

Comment: A well-done lobotomy might actually destroy his power then :P that's really curious.

Comment: Interestingly enough, in one of the Marvel zombie issues, because of his rotten body, he can actually talk without using his power (or rather, he seemed like he couldn't use his "quasi-sonic" anymore).